# How to integrate a Microsoft Power apps application with a script to export and update data automatically

Tags: python, excel, automation, ui-automation, powerapps

I have a Microsoft power apps application that I built and one part of the weekly maintenance to keep this application updated with the correct information is to manually update some sort of data from a weekly excel report, I want to write a code that takes this data from the excel file and automatically updates the current data if needed, Is this possible to integrate some sort of code with power apps applications ? and if it is possible what should I use to do it ? what language and platform ?.

Thank you for everyone who is willing to help I appreciate it A LOT !

description is in the above

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing currently. Are you inserting your data manually into Power Apps components? If so, I believe Power Automate and Microsoft Sharepoint could help you. With your data stored in a Sharepoint List, you could treat it on Power Automate and load it on Power Apps.